# Scaling a matrix by multiple elements of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Assume we have a 4*4 matrix F in a numpy array with shape (4, 4)

```
F=np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
            [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
            [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
            [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

and we want to scale F by every elements in matrix A of shape (3,2)

```
A=np.array([[0, 1],
            [2, 3],
            [4, 5]])
```

so the output is a np.array of shape (3, 2, 4, 4) (containing all the 6 scaled matrices of F) like this:

```
output=array([[[[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
                [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
                [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
                [ 0,  0,  0,  0]],

              [[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
               [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
               [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
               [12, 13, 14, 15]]],


             [[[ 0,  2,  4,  6],
               [ 8, 10, 12, 14],
               [16, 18, 20, 22],
               [24, 26, 28, 30]],

              [[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
               [12, 15, 18, 21],
               [24, 27, 30, 33],
               [36, 39, 42, 45]]],


             [[[ 0,  4,  8, 12],
               [16, 20, 24, 28],
               [32, 36, 40, 44],
               [48, 52, 56, 60]],

              [[ 0,  5, 10, 15],
               [20, 25, 30, 35],
               [40, 45, 50, 55],
               [60, 65, 70, 75]]]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
output = np.einsum('ij,kl->ijkl', A, F)
```

or

```py
output = F * A.reshape((3,2,1,1))
```

Basically, all you need to do is reshape A in a way that each number is in its own nested list. i.e. `[[[[[0]],[[1]]],[[[2]],[[3]]],[[[4]],[[5]]]`.

Answer (score 4):

You can just rely on numpy broadcasting for this:

```py
import numpy as np

F =np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
            [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
            [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
            [12, 13, 14, 15]])

A=np.array([[0, 1],
            [2, 3],
            [4, 5]]) 


F * A[:, :, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
```

Which returns exactly the desired result:

```
array([[[[ 0,  0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0,  0]],

        [[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
         [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14, 15]]],


       [[[ 0,  2,  4,  6],
         [ 8, 10, 12, 14],
         [16, 18, 20, 22],
         [24, 26, 28, 30]],

        [[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
         [12, 15, 18, 21],
         [24, 27, 30, 33],
         [36, 39, 42, 45]]],


       [[[ 0,  4,  8, 12],
         [16, 20, 24, 28],
         [32, 36, 40, 44],
         [48, 52, 56, 60]],

        [[ 0,  5, 10, 15],
         [20, 25, 30, 35],
         [40, 45, 50, 55],
         [60, 65, 70, 75]]]])
```

`np.newaxis` inserts a new axis with size `1`. It is equivalent to `A.reshape((3, 2, 1, 1))` and the standard broadcasting rules apply.

I would recommend to familiarize yourself with Numpy broadcasting: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: `...` is nicer to use than `np.newaxis`

Comment: But `...` and `np.newaxis` are not the same thing! In the example, I showed above I could only use `A[..., np.newaxis, np.newaxis]`, which is slightly more elegant, I agree. But the `np.newaxis` remains.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I meant `None`, so `A[..., None, None]`

Comment: I personally prefer `np.newaxis`, as it is more explicit, but yes, they are equivalent.